# Permission needed to create/remove file in a directory with sticky bit set

Tags: permissions, directory, sticky-bit

I understand that creating/removing a file from a directory with sticky bit set requires one of the followings

- you are root
- you are the owner of the file
- you are the owner of the directory

and you must also have `+w` on the directory.

The problem is with `+x` on the directory. I understand that if sticky bit of the directory is not set, `+x` is needed to create/remove files in it. However, my prof says that if the sticky bit is set, `+x` is not needed.

I tried it on Ubuntu 16.04, and it seems that `+x` is still needed even when the sticky bit is set.

```
Bob@david-VirtualBox:/home/Alice$ ls -ld InBox/
drwx----wT 2 Alice Alice 4096 十一  7 01:09 InBox/
Bob@david-VirtualBox:/home/Alice$ touch InBox/some_file
touch: cannot touch 'InBox/some_file': Permission denied
Bob@david-VirtualBox:/home/Alice$ rm InBox/link
rm: cannot remove 'InBox/link': Permission denied
Bob@david-VirtualBox:/home/Alice$ su Alice
Password: 
Alice@david-VirtualBox:~$ chmod 1703 InBox/
Alice@david-VirtualBox:~$ su Bob
Password: 
Bob@david-VirtualBox:/home/Alice$ touch InBox/some_file
Bob@david-VirtualBox:/home/Alice$ rm InBox/link
Bob@david-VirtualBox:/home/Alice$
```

**My problem**

1. Is this behavior consistent across different distributions or described in some standard?
2. I tried to google, but most resources about sticky bit on directory emphasize the 3 points mentioned above. I'd like to know if there is some (historical?) reason why my prof says so.

In case somebody asks, I would have asked my prof directly if he replies my email :(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe your professor meant, x (the alphabet)  is replaced by t (the alphabet) when sticky bit is set. This does not mean x (the permission) is not needed anymory. The directory must have x (execute) permission to cd into that directory. If permission is set to 1703, user can create, write, read, remove files in that directory, cd into the directory but can NOT ls into the directory.

Comment: Excellent identification of the "sticky" bit.  I usually see this used incorrectly to describe a different set of bits.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is wrong:

If you like to remove something from a directory you need the so called "search permission" and this is granted by the x bit on the directory.

If you don't have the x bit, you are not allowed to verify whether the file to be removed is present.